# Running a value through an array of functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I have a form handling system set up where I can pass value formatting options that will change the input to fit a certain formatting (for instance stripping non-number values, enforcing max-length, adding hyphens at every X interval etc) and I want to create a function that creates a combined formatter of an arbitrary number of more minute formatters, and runs the value through these in order.

For instance a formatter could be, in the case of numbers only:

```
const numberFormatter = value => value.replace(.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
```

But I also have createFormatter functions, like for max length:

```
export const createMaxLengthFormatter = (maxLength) => (value) => value
  .slice(0, maxLength);
```

The way I use them is usually like this:

```
const someNumberInput = createFormField({
   ...otherParams,
  valueFormatter: createMaxLengthFormatter(8),
})
```

However I want to be able to do something akin to this:

```
const someFourDigitNumberInput = createFormField({
  ...otherParams,
  valueFormatter: combineFormatters(numberFormatter, createMaxLengthFormatter(4)),
});
```

Any suggestions how to implement combineFormatters **in an elegant ESNEXT way**?

Comment: you want to compose the two functions. googling for es6 compose functions will answer your question. function composition is a general concept.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @AndyRay ! Looking up on it now

Comment: Hmm, I ended up with a solution kind of based on the documentation I found on es6 composing, just a bit simplified using `.reduce` to iterate and use the value of the previous computation as the input for the next.

I guess I'll share my own answer but see if something more elegant pops up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to @andy-ray pointing me in the right direction I ended up with one solution that seems to be working fine:

```
export const combineFormatters = (...formatters) => (value) => formatters
  .reduce((currentValue, formatter) => formatter(currentValue), value);
```

Leaving it up as a solution for now, but not marking it as the correct one in case somebody comes up with a more elegant/correct solution for this problem. Though it does indeed seem to be doing the job as intended.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I was about to post, so I think it's a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case of [function composition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). The `compose` high order function would goes like:

```js
// compose from right to left
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => x => f(g(x)))

// compose from left to right
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce((f, g) => x => g(f(x)))
```

I would say this implementation is elegant in the sense that it looks so close to the mathematical expression. Pleasing to the eye!

However it will produce a deep calling stack, because of the function-inside-function form. Your implementation would be more memory friendly, and is equivalent in effect.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah it's absolutely beautiful to look at, but I see what you mean, the recursive nature of it would increase the callstack. So I guess in my specific case reusing the result and successively calling funcitons with the previous output is more efficient.

Comment: I would just say it's more memory efficient. CPU efficiency is theoretically identical. The difference is the order of calling CPU instructions, not the number of instructions.